# Set cron expression to current time?

Tags: apex, scheduled-apex, scheduled-job

What is the best way to schedule a job on the current date and time? Will the `System.now()` function work for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you cannot do it via the UI you will have to use code or dev console.

As such, no need to use cron at all.

Simply instantiate the batch and execute it.

```
Database.executeBatch( new batchClassName(), 20);
```

Change the 20 to whatever size u need

Comment: well firstly I am calling the Scheduler and then in the scheduler Execute function I am doing Database.executeBatch();

Comment: @Malik you are wrong. Not sure I can explain any differently if you do not understand that simply running the code inside the schedule execute method like in my answer is the same as scheduling to run now without the need to mess with cron. Your stuck on wanting to schedule  to run now when u do not need to schedule. It's like telling you to set an alarm to eat now.  Just eat

Comment: I don't want to call the batch directly....in Schedule i have put batch size

Comment: @Malik forget the schedualeable class. You don't need it for this. All you need to do is execute the batch. You can set the size when you call the batch. See updated answer

Comment: @Eric I am working in sandbox its not working but when I work through schedule it works...

Comment: @Malik - Post both your schedule class and the code you are using outside of the schedule class. You are doing something wrong or checking the wrong place to see if it ran. Also, how are you verifying "Works"

Comment: Sorry for being late is there any Interface if I run the batch how can I see it that how much its completed as I am putting a check in database where its not becoming false is there any interface where I can see it

Comment: the Other Thing like if i execute the batch and want to execute it gain through another function will it be possible? or this the new update will be in Queue?